# How put a math expression in chapter heading?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, chapters, classicthesis

I have trouble when put an equation with exponents in the \chapter.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis-ldpkg}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sistem A: $L(\dot{q}_2,\dot{q}_2)=\dot{q}_1^2+\dot{q}_2^{2}$}

\end{document}
```

But it gives me multiple errors that doesn't appear when I compile, in the index contents appears the equation if I change \chapter for \section instruction, but I need put this in the chapter. Any help?

Comment: i don't have `classicthesis-ldpkg.sty` and it doesn't appear to be on ctan.  without that, the example file compiles with no errors.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292765/89662) there is a good answer that point out why you shouldn't use the `classicthesis-ldpkg` package, even if you want to use `classicthesis` style.

Comment: Try `\texorpdfstring{$math$}{Non math for e.g. TOC}` as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/equations-in-section-heading-title).

Answer (score 0):

`classicthesis-ldpkg` is outdated. It was replaced by [`classicthesis-config.tex`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis-config.tex) and it's just a configuration file that at the end load `classicthesis`. I suggest you to simply use `classicthesis` and load only the packages that you want to use.